# Same Firebird Database file connects on linux but not on windows

Tags: firebird

I have a production database running on a Windows Server 2008 64bit (NTFS). Suddenly it became impossible to connect to this database, there is no error message, it just takes forever to connect.

If I simply copy the file to a linux computer it connects instantly without any problem.

I tested in other 2 windows (8 and 7) and in both cases it happens the same error.

I testes also in other 2 linux computers and it will always connect perfectly.

There is no relevant messages in the FB log.

What could be causing this? How can I investigate further?

Comment: Did you try to test connect with IBExpert, etc? There is a button "Test connect" in database registration info dialog.

Comment: Have you restarted Firebird on the windows machine? Checked the database with [gfix](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix.html)? Note that stackoverflow might not be the right venue for troubleshooting these types of problems. I suggest you post to the firebird-support mailinglist instead. It would also be helpful to specify the Firebird version used.

Comment: You should really post in the firebird-support mailing-list. But checking the database using gfix in booth, Windows and Linux, could probably help to get some messages.